# Achar valores em comum em dois dataframes diferentes

Tags: python-2.7, data.frame

Editando a pergunta:

Eu tenho dois DataFrames de tamanhos diferentes, sao eles:

```
 df1 = pd.DataFrame({'bc': bc_1}, index=altura_1)    
 df1.shape()=(73,1)
 >>> print df1
             bc
  1.175441  0.002884
  1.115565  0.001905
  1.055689  0.003029
  0.995812  0.003366
  .
  .
  .

 df2 = pd.DataFrame({'bc': bc_2}, index=altura_2)    
 df2.shape()=(18,1)
 >>> print df2
            bc
  0.150  0.000005
  0.165  0.000007
  0.180  0.000010
  .
  .
  .
```

E eles estão medindo a mesma variável, só que utilizando dois instrumentos diferentes.

O grafico que representa esses dados esta a seguir:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Percebem que em alguns momentos, as curvas (os pontos) ficam muito proximas(os)?
Eu preciso descobrir quais sao esses pontos e armazena-los em outro dataframe

Comment: Poderia editar a pergunta adicionando exemplos? Como um pedacinho de cada dataframe e a saída esperada?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partindo destes dois dataframes:

```
>>> print df1
       dados
1.1    1.123
2.2    1.567
3.3    2.001
4.4    2.345

>>> print df2
       dados
1.0     1.12
2.3     1.56
3.5     2.00
```

Calculo a distância de dois pontos em um gráfico:

```
def calc_distancia(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    return ((x1-x2)**2 + (y1-y2)**2) ** (1/2.0)
```

Agora, definimos um df3 e calculamos a distância dos pontos de df1 e df2. Se a distância for menor que um valor, adicionamos o dado no df3:

```
DISTANCIA_MAXIMA = 0.5#Defini a distância máxima como 0.5

df3 = pd.DataFrame(data={'X1':[], 'Y1':[], 'X2':[], 'Y2':[], 'Distancia':[]})
#Verifia quais valores são iguais comparando todos os dados1 com todos os dados2
for index_df1, row_df1 in df1.iterrows():
    for index_df2, row_df2 in df2.iterrows():
        distancia = calc_distancia(index_df1, row_df1['dados'], index_df2, row_df2['dados'])
        if distancia < DISTANCIA_MAXIMA:
            df3 = df3.append({'X1':index_df1, 'Y1':row_df1['dados'], 'X2':index_df2, 'Y2':row_df2['dados'], 'Distancia':distancia}, ignore_index=True)

>>> print df3
   Distancia   X1   X2     Y1    Y2
0   0.100045  1.1  1.0  1.123  1.12
1   0.100245  2.2  2.3  1.567  1.56
2   0.200002  3.3  3.5  2.001  2.00
```

Comment: Eu usei essa logica que voce sugeriu, mas o dataframe resultante (df3) ficou com mais de 400 linhas quando na verdade, era para ele ter ficado menor que os outros dois. Eu editei a pergunta com os dados como voce pediu. Acho que agora esta mais facil para entender o que eu preciso fazer. Obrigada

Comment: @Luana ficou mais fácil haha. Veja se com a edição que fiz você consegue aplicar para o seu problema.

Comment: Ficou sim! Obrigada! Eu entendi o que voce fez, mas agora preciso fazer de uma outra maneira...Eu preciso achar onde a diferenca de altura eh minima (y1 e y2) e armazenar os valores de x refentes a esse ponto. Meu dataframe final tem que ter o mesmo numero de pontos do meu menor dataframe..no caso, df2..Deu pra entender? Estou com certa dificuldade para fazer isso tambem

Comment: @Luana se surgiu um novo problema que precisa de uma resposta diferente, faça uma outra pergunta abordando o novo problema.

Comment: Na verdade a pergunta eh a mesma...a abordagem p/ resolver que eh um pouco diferente da que vc sugeriu, ja que ao inves de calcular a distancia usando x e y, eu preciso levar somente o y em consideracao...Mas obrigada de qualquer forma